# Hide layer name in map legend using python in QGIS 2.16

Tags: qgis, python, legend, qgis-python-console

I am trying to render the layer in QGIS as a map using python console.  I am using `QgsComposerLegend()` for drawing the legend in the map.

Is it possible to make the layer name hidden in the map legend using python console?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Setting layer name in composer legend as “Hidden” using PyQGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223001/setting-layer-name-in-composer-legend-as-hidden-using-pyqgis)